# Java stops capturing mouse movement events after maximizing or full screening a window in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, swing

When I enlarge a window by either pressing the maximize button or the full screen button on OS X, mouse movement events are no longer captured (though dragging is).

I have included a demo program below that highlights the issue. The maximization problem can be replicated using the [MouseEventDemo web start example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/samples/uiswing/MouseEventDemoProject/MouseEventDemo.jnlp) on the [Java Tutorials website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

After some troubleshooting, I noted that mouse movements are recaptured if the mouse leaves the window (e.g., moves to the top of the window to access the menu bar) and then returns. It seems the issue may have something to do with the relation between the mouse position and the window during resizing animations, since the mouse is not in the frame before the resizing, but is afterward even though it didn’t necessarily move in the process.

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main implements MouseMotionListener {

    JLabel label = new JLabel("label");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.init();
    }

    public void init() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        if (isMacOSX()) {
            enableFullScreenMode(frame);
        }
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        label.setText(e.toString());
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        label.setText(e.toString());
    }

    private static boolean isMacOSX() {
        return System.getProperty("os.name").indexOf("Mac OS X") >= 0;
    }

    public static void enableFullScreenMode(Window window) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities");
            Method method = clazz.getMethod("setWindowCanFullScreen", new Class<?>[] { Window.class, boolean.class });
            method.invoke(null, window, true);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Running the code above should reveal when the label does and does not update.

I am running OS X Version 10.9 Build 13A3017 with Java SE 7 [1.7.0_45].

Comment: @Petesh, I meant to ask if there was a solution for this issue, or a known workaround since it seems like it would be a common problem. I have notified Oracle about the issue since they ask for problems with the examples in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle responded to [the bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8036935) I submitted, noting in their comments that the issue should be resolved in Java 8. The code above works as expected on the 1.8.0 JRE (build 1.8.0-b132) using OS X 10.9.2.

Answer (score 7):

Empirically, the problem disappears if one switches away from and back to the application while maximized. Adding a `ComponentListener` that forces the frame `toFront()` seems to work. As an aside, Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

```
frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        frame.toFront();
    }
});
```

As tested:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054242/230513 */
public class Main implements MouseMotionListener {

    JLabel label = new JLabel("label");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Main main = new Main();
                main.init();
            }
        });
    }

    public void init() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        if (isMacOSX()) {
            enableFullScreenMode(frame);
        }
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                frame.toFront();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        label.setText(e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        label.setText(e.toString());
    }

    private static boolean isMacOSX() {
        return System.getProperty("os.name").indexOf("Mac OS X") >= 0;
    }

    public static void enableFullScreenMode(Window window) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities");
            Method method = clazz.getMethod("setWindowCanFullScreen",
                    new Class<?>[]{Window.class, boolean.class});
            method.invoke(null, window, true);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem does seem to disappear upon application switching. Here is [a citation to the full screen icon code](http://saipullabhotla.blogspot.com/2012/05/enabling-full-screen-mode-for-java.html). Interestingly, your code fixes the issue upon pressing the full screen icon, but not the maximize button. Is this the case for you?

Comment: Yes, maximize button interferers with mouse moved events; I didn't notice, as application switching also restores the listener. Mouse motion on components seems unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a work around to the maximized part of this issue by adding a windowStateListener to the frame and doing the following:

```
frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener()
{
    @Override
    public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e)
    {
        if (Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH == e.getNewState())
        {
            frame.toBack();
            frame.toFront();
        }
    }
});
```

If you combine this with the resize work around from trashgod you should be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

The events mouseReleased, mouseClicked are not triggered when jdk 1.6.0_65 (yosemite) is use, for jdk 1.8.0_25 (yosemite) the events are triggered and also that events were triggered on jdk 1.6 (maverick). What might be the issue?

java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)

windowActivated
windowOpened
mousePressed
windowClosing
windowDeactivated

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

windowActivated
windowOpened
mousePressed
mouseReleased
mouseClicked
windowClosing
windowDeactivated

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestMouseEventsOnYosemite {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestFrame testFrame = new TestFrame();
    testFrame.setVisible(true);
    testFrame.toFront();
}

public static class TestFrame extends Frame implements WindowListener {

    public TestFrame() {
        setLayout(null);
        addNotify();
        Button okButon = new Button("    Ok    ");
        add(okButon);

        okButon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("mouseReleased");
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("mousePressed");
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("mouseClicked");
            }
        }
        );

        okButon.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
                System.out.println("keyPressed");
            }
        }
        );

        int dy = okButon.getPreferredSize().height;

        okButon.setBounds(30, 50, 100, dy);

        setSize(150, 150);
        addWindowListener(this);
        setResizable(true);
        okButon.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("windowActivated");
    }

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("windowClosed");
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("windowDeactivated");
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("windowDeiconified");
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("windowIconified");
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("windowOpened");
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("windowClosing");
    }
}
```

}