# How to programmatically zoom JFrame window on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, swing, zooming, maximize

I am adding a menu item to the menu bar for my Java application (if using OS X) titled Zoom (aka expand, maximize). Upon clicking it, it should trigger the green zoom stoplight button. I figured out how to programmatically enter Full Screen and minimize to the Dock (`setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);`), but I have not found a way to initiate zoom. Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: is `setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's almost perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Consider asking @vandale to post this as an answer; see also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20053223/230513)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to vandale, here is the answer should anyone else stumble upon this question:

Use `setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`to initiate zoom.

But realize this is not a toggle, so clicking it again doesn't unzoom like other Mac apps. Here is the necessary code to make it a toggle:

```
if (yourFrame.getExtendedState() != 6)
    setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
else
    setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL);
```

Zoomed mode is state 6, normal is 0.