# Setting fullscreen using other ways besides getting screen size in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen

I was wondering if there was a way that is better than using the `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()/getWidth();` and then using that as the dimensions for the JFrame and then setting the JFrame to `undecorated`? Would there be some sort of pre-built function in Java that takes control of the graphics card for a true fullscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after what's called "full-screen exclusive mode"

Have a look at [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/) for more details.

Understand though, it doesn't play well with Swing.

Under Mac OS X 10.7, you can access the full screen support it provides for applications using  `com.apple.eawt.Application.requestToggleFullScreen(Window)`.

Take a look at [Fullscreen feature for Java Apps on OSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873568/fullscreen-feature-for-java-apps-on-osx-lion) for more details

Comment: A complete example may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20054242/230513).