# MouseMotionListener events don't fire in certain areas of the screen

Tags: java, macos, swing, mouselistener

The following class demonstrates a problem I am having with MouseMotionListeners in FSEM.

```
public class TestGUI extends JFrame {

Panel panel;

public TestGUI()
{
    panel = new Panel();
    GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    gd.setFullScreenWindow(this);
    setVisible(false); // use the workaround to the Mac OS X FSEM bug where mouseMotionListeners don't work right away
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
}

class Panel extends JPanel
{
    public Panel()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
            {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestGUI();
}
}
```

The problem is this: I can clearly hear when a mouseEvent fires because of the `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();` call in the event handler. The event handler works perfectly fine for most of the screen, *except* for the area of the screen that normally has the [Mac OS X dock](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2474). I confirmed this by pinning the dock to various sides of my screen, and the "dead-zone" changed to the side of the screen that I pinned the dock on. Is there a workaround for this?

My setup:

Java version: 1.7.0_55.

Mac OS X version: 10.8.5.

Comment: Set the background of the window to make sure it's filling the entire area. This might be a limition of Mac OS

Comment: You might also consider using Mac OS's own "full screen" API, as demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924553/setting-fullscreen-using-other-ways-besides-getting-screen-size-in-java/23924624#23924624)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Setting the background color makes it obvious that the entire screen area is being covered.

Comment: There could be an invisible system window which is used to detect mouse movement over the "dock bar" region.  Consider using the `com.apple.eawt.Application.requestToggleFullScreen(Window)` API instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The solution is to set the frame `undecorated(true);` right before setting it as the fullscreen window.

```
public TestGUI()
{
    panel = new Panel();
    GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    setUndecorated(true);
    gd.setFullScreenWindow(this);
    setVisible(false); // use the workaround to the Mac OS X FSEM bug where mouseMotionListeners don't work right away
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Perhaps there was some invisible non-windowey thing in front of the dock.