# Maximizing a JFrame causes MouseMoved events to stop firing

Tags: java, macos, swing, mouseevent

It seems that I keep finding more issues with MouseMotion listeners on Mac OS X. I've made another small example that illustrates the problem.

```
public class TestGUI extends JFrame {

Panel panel;

public TestGUI()
{
    setSize(1000, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    panel = new Panel();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
}

class Panel extends JPanel
{
    private Point mouseLocation = new Point();
    public Panel()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
            {
                mouseLocation = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("(" + mouseLocation.x + "," + mouseLocation.y + ")", 100, 100);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestGUI();
}
}
```

I'm not sure if this happens on windows because I don't currently have access to a windows computer, but on OS X the following happens:

Clicking the green '+' to maximize the window causes the window to maximize, and therefore causes the mouse pointer to be back in the canvas area. However if you don't click, the text that says the mouse location will stop updating.

I know that it's not the window loosing focus: I checked this by adding a focusAdapter to the panel and adding a `System.out.println()` to the method.

I am using JDK 1.7 on Mac OS X 10.8.5

The answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053223/java-stops-capturing-mouse-movement-events-after-maximizing-or-full-screening-a?lq=1) question do not work for me. As a matter of fact the test case on the accepted answer doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: Your code works fine on my Windows 7 machine. 1+ to your question, and let's wait and see what answers come this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the answer that was linked in the question doesn't help, then you can get around this in another way.

Instead of using a `mouseMotionAdapter` (or `Listener`) you can instead use an `ScheduledExecutorService` (or another type of timer if you prefer), to get at a constant rate, the mouse position. The window doesn't even have to have focus for you to do this.

The small program below demonstrates that maximizing the window does not have any effect on the tracking of the mouse's position.

```
public class TestGUI extends JFrame {

Panel panel;
Point mouseLocation = new Point();
Dimension borderSize = new Dimension();
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
public TestGUI()
{
    setSize(1000, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    panel = new Panel();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
    borderSize.setSize(getSize().width - getContentPane().getSize().width, getSize().height - getContentPane().getSize().height);
    ex.schedule(new UpdatingService(), 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

class Panel extends JPanel
{
    public Panel()
    {
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("(" + mouseLocation.x + "," + mouseLocation.y + ")", 100, 100);
    }
}

private void checkMouse()
{
    mouseLocation.x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - this.getLocationOnScreen().x - borderSize.width;
    mouseLocation.y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - this.getLocationOnScreen().y - borderSize.height;
    repaint();
}

class UpdatingService implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        checkMouse();
        ex.schedule(new UpdatingService(), 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestGUI();
}
}
```

Here's how the program works: First it calculates the size of the border of the window, this varies from computer to computer. Then every 10 milliseconds the `ScheduledExecutorService` gets the location of the mouse on the screen (this might be way too frequently, play around with the delay and see if there's an optimal time). It does this by first finding the location of the mouse on the entire screen then subtracting the location of the `JFrame`, and then finally subtracts the thickness of the border.

It is worth noting that this program continues tracking the mouse outside of the window, but a simple if statement could be written (or a `MouseAdapter` could be used) to stop recording from happening if the mouse is outside the window.

I've found that it is possible that it is neccecary to use `setPreferredSize` and `pack()` in order for the border dimensions calculations to work. I don't know for sure but I believe this happens in java versions 7+

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the issue on OS X 10.9.3 using JDK1.7.

What I see that is happening is that when you move your mouse to the window decoration bar containing the green '+' symbol, your mouse is leaving the panel. This can be seen by attaching a `MouseListener` to it

```
public Panel()
{
  addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) {
      System.out.println( "TestGUI.Panel.mouseEntered" );
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ) {
      System.out.println( "TestGUI.Panel.mouseExited" );
    }
  } );
  addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
      mouseLocation = e.getPoint();
      repaint();
    }
  });
  setVisible(true);
}
```

When you press the '+' symbol, the window will indeed maximize causing your cursor to get back inside the panel. However, I do not get a `mouseEntered` event. So moving the mouse does not trigger the `mouseMoved` event as as far as Swing is concerned, the mouse hasn't even entered the component.
Only when moving my mouse outside the maximised window again and re-entering, I get the `mouseEntered` event and the `mouseMoved` is triggered again.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20053223/1076463), it is solved in JDK8. Tested this on my machine, and indeed, switching to JDK8 solves the issue. If that is not an option for you, you could try to use the workarounds mentioned in that other question.